# Typed text unreadable in chat when using high-contrast color scheme

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, chat

When using Windows 7 with a high contrast-black color scheme, the text you type in the chat box is unreadable. The background is set fixed on yellow, but the text takes the default, which is white in my case (have to think about my eyes, staring at a computer all day...). Hence, I can't read what I type there. This problem doesn't occur on the site itself, as that one takes the default background too (black in my case) for the typing boxes.

Windows 7 64 bit running latest Firefox. Windows aero is off. The color seen in the chatbox is nowhere to be found in my color scheme, so it must be coming from the site.

See screenshots.

### My settings :

[image]

### The question box :

[image]

### Chat box - with text!!! -

[image]

### As seen here :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fixed -- chat will no longer take the default textbox colors from the OS.