# Provide better support for users using black backgrounds

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Like many programmers working long hours in front of monitors, I prefer to use a dark background theme for my browser.

When using Stack Overflow under the Windows black background theme, there are un-viewable features. The most disruptive problem is that it's hard to tell whether an answer has been marked accepted.

EDIT: Screenshot using Windows 7's High Contrast Black theme; this question *does* have an accepted answer.
[image: Windows 7 high-contrast black theme]

Comment: Related: [Make a dark theme available for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/make-a-dark-theme-available-for-stack-overflow) - Although that one's about custom CSS; this one seems to be about Windows themes.  How does the black background affect the visibility of the webpage?  Is your browser background transparent?

Comment: @KevinVermeer the theme affects it. I'm adding a screenshot.

Comment: See also [May 13, 2010 updates break high contrast Windows mode](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49769/may-13-2010-updates-break-high-contrast-windows-mode)

Comment: Never having used Windows 7 themes, that seems like really weird behavior.  Nonetheless, I also found this bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68299/typed-text-unreadable-in-chat-when-using-high-contrast-color-scheme